# Cannot type PINCODE number into digit, cypress not support cy.type() to this field

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, pin-code

Got an issue with the cypress test cannot cover pincode functionality with the cypress test because I tried using cy.type() but got an error. My function to receive this element works when I check him for visibility but when I wanna type the pin code it failed with an error

> `pinCodeDigit() {return cy.get('[data-testid="pin-digit-0"]');}`

How I use this In a test `pinCodeDigit().type('1111');`

`cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.

The element typed into was:

> `<div data-testid="pin-digit-0" class="_digit_1lwa4_26"></div>`

A typeable element matches one of the following selectors:
a[href]
area[href]
input
select
textarea
button
iframe
[tabindex]
[contenteditable]`

How can I put Pincode to pin-digit in cypress what method should I choose?

[image][image]

I tried to modify my function like this but nothing helped.

`pinCodeDigit() {return cy.get('[data-testid="pin-digit-*"]'); }`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that elements `<div data-testid="pin-digit-0">` are ***only*** for displaying the digits as you type them, but there is another element in that block that accepts the typed digits.

Try searching for an `<input>`

```js
cy.get('div[data-testid="check-pin"]`)
  .find('input')
  .type('1111')
```